# React native bundlle js stuck

Tags: android, gradle, react-native

When I run `react-native run-android --variant=Release` or any other variant I defined in `build.gradle` I got stuck on `Building 91% > :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets`. If I run just debug it works fine. It happens as well when running `./gradlew assambleRelease`.

When I manually run `Build apk` from Android Studio, then it successfully creates the apks.

EDIT: When I run apk generated from Android Studio, the app crashes on run. I expect this is due AppRegistry.registerComponent fails when you usually run the app trough studio not trough react-native cli

Comment: Personally, I am never using the `react-native run-android` because I'm always having problems with it. I'm just starting react-native using `npm start` and then I'm running the build on Android Studio.

Answer (score -1):

Usually it takes time in first round. Just try again and in my case it took around 10 mins to build the release.

Comment: Funny thing is, that this was building ok few days back.